# Meteor Jade: Helper function with parameter in attribute

Tags: meteor, pug, helper

I'm doing something like this:

```
img(src="#{getGravatarUrl username}")
```

Where my helper function looks like this:

```
...
getGravatarUrl: function (username) { ... },
...
```

I think that roughly equals what's said in the meteor-jade readme. However, this literally compiles to `<img src="#{getGravatarUrl username}">`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jade currently doesn't support inline js expressions, so you need to write:

```
img(src="{{getGravatarUrl username}}")
```

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade/issues/30).